# How to find type of a function in Elm repl

Tags: function, types, read-eval-print-loop, elm

In Haskell you can use `:t` to find type of a function in ghci, is there an equivalent in elm repl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't try this out because I currently don't have a working `elm-repl` but off the top of my head, you can just type the function name in the repl and it will answer with the type of the function. This is because the Elm repl will always print the type after a resulting value, so if you input a function name, it will print `<function>` for the value, followed by the type:

```
> not

<function> : Bool -> Bool

>
```

Comment: I only see <function> in my repl, any idea why?

Comment: @Arif try changing your terminal's background color - this just stumped me for an hour! Mine matched the color of the REPL banner and the type signatures